# Automatically setting foreign keys & autonumbers in new DataGridView rows?

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I have an order table with the following columns:

```
orderid, clientid, [columns for order details] ...
```

I am then displaying this table, for a specific client, using a DataGridView. I have both the `orderid` and `clientid` columns hidden, however, as the `orderid` is a autonumbered primary key and the `clientid` is constant.

Unfortunately, when new rows are added to the DataGridView they are not persisted to the database. I believe this is because the `orderid` defaults to **-1** and/or the `clientid` defaults to **null** whenever a new row is inserted into the DataGridView, but because those columns are hidden the user cannot change them.

*So, my question:*

How can I get the `orderid` to be selected automatically and have the `clientid` default to the currently displayed client, whenever a new row is inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I can trap the UserAddedRow event and manually set the correct value there:

```
private void myDataGridView_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    myDataGridView[clientidColumn.Index, e.Row.Index - 1].Value = clientid;
}
```

This now correctly persists the new orders to the database, although it seems a bit hacky (why must it be `e.Row.Index - 1`?). Is there not a way to specify the default values for columns on new rows?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a Master/Detail form

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey.aspx